# react-script build replaces var() in scss files incorrectly

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, variables, sass

I'm using create react app 4.0.3 with node-sass 6.0.1 sass-loader 11.0.1. When I try to build my project the compiled version of css file has wrong var() replacements. I have some scss files that I import at corresponding component .tsx like.

```
import "../assets/scss/products.scss"
```

I have my :root variables defined in index.scss and it's imported in index.tsx like

```
import './index.scss';
```

My usage in scss file is like

```
background-color: var(--white);
```

And it compiles to

```
background-color: var(#fff);
```

I believe some of the packages got updated and broke this because in the past it was not like this

Comment: maybe one to flag with  node-sass

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with

- sass@1.43.5
- sass-loader@10.2.0
- react-scripts@4.0.3

`color: var(--gray-color-30)` compiled into `color: var(gray)`.
For other color variables not prefixed with "gray", it is ok.

I was able to fix it by renaming all my variables prefixed with "gray".
For example: `var(--gray-color-30)` becomes `var(--color-gray-30)`.

Comment: This is not an answer, don't ask anoter question inside an answer please.